# Javascript array inherit keys of object

Tags: javascript

I'm used to program on PowerShell and fairly new to JavaScript.
In PowerShell you can create an array of custom objects like that :
You have an object with 3 properties of value 1,2,3 for $item1 :

```
Property1 Property2 Property3
--------- --------- ---------
        1         2         3
```

Same properties with values 10,20,30 for $item2

```
Property1 Property2 Property3
--------- --------- ---------
       10        20        30
```

And if you add them to an arraylist it automatically inherits their properties :

```
$collectionVariable = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$collectionVariable.Add($item) | Out-Null
$collectionVariable.Add($item2) | Out-Null
$collectionVariable

Property1 Property2 Property3
--------- --------- ---------
        1         2         3
       10        20        30
```

I have tried to do the same in JavaScript but ultimately failed as each added object appears as a new key.

```
var arraylist = new Array();
arraylist.push(item);
```

It seems that it does not work that way as the arraylist does not inherit item's keys.

How can I do so that my arraylist inherit the keys of my objects ?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what exactly you are wanting. `let object1 = {prop1: 1, prop2: 2, prop3: 3}, object2 = {prop1: 10, prop2: 20, prop3: 30};` With an array that looks like `let array = [[1,10], [2,20], [3,30]];` or something else.

Comment: Is that an accurate description of how it works in PowerShell, or is what’s actually happening an intelligent display of a homogeneous ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` is a rather dumb (and IMO very much outdated) collection type. It only supports the .NET type `Object`, and it certainly does not *inherit* anything.

**PowerShell** on the other hand has smart logic to see beyond the stored objects and to print them using their properties, and to group on those properties if they are the same. What you see printed is because PowerShell is smart, not because ArrayList is smart (on the contrary).

**Javascript** has a similarly smart printing function, and that is [`console.table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/table):

```js
var items = [];
items.push({ prop1: 1, prop2: 2, prop3: 3 });
items.push({ prop1: 10, prop2: 20, prop3: 30 });

console.table(items); // Run, then do F12, then look in "Console" tab
```

To see the results you need to Run the snippet, then press **F12** to open the *Developer Tools*, then look in the "Console" tab to see the output. Here is a screenshot of it:

> [image: Screenshot of Console output]

Comment: Oh OK, thank you ! The table indeed represents what I want to achieve. So, I guess if I want some kind of table that I can easily browse - for example, add, update or delete a value with a "where" condition I have to use this kind of array with its "some" method ?
For example, if I want to check if or where I have the value "30" I'd have to do something like `items.some(o => o.prop3 === 30)`.
OR is there some kind of variable in Javascript that is more convenient for this kind of operations ?

Comment: It is best not to ask follow-up questions in comments if that leads us to a subject or scope that is totally different from the original question. Better is to [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in such cases. Furthermore if you found my answer to your original question useful, then please consider Upvoting and/or Accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Make items into objects and push to the array:

```
const item = {
   prop1: 1,
   prop2: 2,
   prop3: 3
}

arr.push(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your **keys** of **object** to be **elements** of the **array** **list** :
Do this ,

```js
const item = {
   prop1: 1,
   prop2: 2,
   prop3: 3
}

let arr = Object.keys(item);
console.log(arr)
```

If you want , **values** of **object** to be **elements** of **array list** , do this :

```js
const item = {
   prop1: 1,
   prop2: 2,
   prop3: 3
}

let arr = Object.values(item)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: `Object.keys`/`values` already return an array. No need to spread.

Comment: But , it returns a reference to that array , so I am using a spread operator inorder , not to use a reference of original array rather create a new array

Comment: Am I correct with my thought ? Or , using reference of the original array works ?

Comment: It returns a new array each time; there’s no actual array of keys or values inside the object.

Comment: Ohh , yess , Got it , thanks ! I will now edit it and improve it .